# Replacing a string found in a list with a string

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

Using tidyverse, across the entire data frame, replacing any string found on a list, with a string.

```
df<- tribble(
  ~x, ~y,  ~z,
  "a", "95%",  "96%",
  "b", "99%",  "98%",
  "c", "astricks", "astricks"
)

high95 <- c("95%", "96%", "97%", "98%", "99%", "100%")
```

Trying to replace any string in the list (high95) with the string ">95%"

```
df %>% str_replace(. %in% high95, ">95%")
```

I am doing this with strings because of suppression changing col to a character format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `replace` to create the logical expression

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
   mutate(across(y:z, ~ replace(., . %in% high95, ">95%")))
```

-output

```
df
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  x     y        z       
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>   
1 a     >95%     >95%    
2 b     >95%     >95%
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `high95` to create a regex that matches these values and use this regex in `str_replace`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df<- tribble(
  ~x, ~y,  ~z,
  "a", "95%",  "96%",
  "b", "99%",  "98%",
  "c", "astricks", "astricks"
)

high95 <- c("95%", "96%", "97%", "98%", "99%", "100%")
regex_95 <- paste0("(", paste0(high95, collapse = "|"), ")")
regex_95
#> [1] "(95%|96%|97%|98%|99%|100%)"

df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~str_replace(.x, regex_95, ">95%")))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   x     y        z       
#>   <chr> <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1 a     >95%     >95%    
#> 2 b     >95%     >95%    
#> 3 c     astricks astricks
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Different option using `replace`:

```
data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) {replace(x, x %in% high95, ">95%")}))
```

Output:

```
  x        y        z
1 a     >95%     >95%
2 b     >95%     >95%
3 c astricks astricks
```